# Subsequent lines in working for an inequality

Tags: inequality, notation

This is a question of notation and correctness. When showing a worked solution for an inequality, which is more appropriate?

$$ \begin{align} a & \ge (b + c)^2 \\ & \ge b^2+2bc+c^2 \end{align} $$
vs
$$ \begin{align} a & \ge (b + c)^2 \\ & = b^2+2bc+c^2 \end{align} $$
The former is only correct if it is implied that the LHS is repeated on each line, whereas the latter is only correct if we read it as though the  line break is not important. Perhaps one should always explicitly include the LHS for inequalities?

Edit: for another example, here's a problem I encountered today:

Given $\Delta t \ge 2.3$ and $v=2.1$ from a previous problem,
$$ \begin{align} \Delta x & = v \Delta t \\ & \ge 2.3 \times 2.1 \\ & = 4.83 \end{align} $$

In this case, even reading the first and last lines does not tell you that the answer is actually $\Delta x \ge 4.83$. If there were several pages of working, rather than one line, this seems like a problem.

Comment: former and the latter are the same?

Comment: The latter is common usage, and a lot more clear. Each (in)equality in a chain should be able to stand on its own. In other words $x \ge y = z$ is just shorthand for $x \ge y \;\land\; y = z\,$, regardless of whether you write it on one line or split it between multiple lines.

Comment: Since in you didn't carry the LHS down (in either example), I would interpret it is as saying that the RHS of the first line is [comparison operator] to the RHS of the second line. While that's true for both, the second one is more instantly clear, as well as more precise. You can't go wrong with the second one.

Comment: And yet, if you're skimming and just want the answer, so you don't read the working lines, it's easier to miss that it's an inequality if the inequality only appears on the first line. On the other hand, the variable itself only appears on the first line, too, so perhaps that's okay. If that's the convention, then so be it.

Comment: if the first is true and in the most simplified form,  the second can be true.

Comment: @dxiv  and quasi, I've edited the question to add another example. While I basically accept your answers, the new example shows why this might be a problem.

Comment: @Widjet `the new example shows why this might be a problem` I don't see a problem with the new example, either. `even reading the first and last lines` That's no way to read a proof if you care at all, regardless of how it's laid out in the page. `If there were several pages of working` Then I would seriously suggest the author reorganized that proof. Note also that "page" is relative, my page on a desktop screen is different from someone else's page on a smartphone. Good, consistent writeup should not make unnecessary (and untenable) assumptions about the particular layout each user will see.